# How to set download expiration to output URN on Design Automation API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Please tell me how to delete result content from S3, Or change the content expiration to short.
By security reasons, I don't want to keep the result content on S3 for one hour.

I try to delete Output files from "https://acadio.s3.amazonaws.com/aces-workitem-outputs/****". Although, I couldn't delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 2 of the API we provide "temporary storage" when you don't specify output URLs in your workitem. This temporary storage is https://acadio.s3.amazonaws.com/aces-workitem-outputs/. You cannot delete or customize this.

If you want full control over your outputs then I recommend that you don't use "temporary storage". You simply specify non-null output URLs in your workitem.

BTW, in version 3 of the API we no longer offer this temporary storage so as to avoid the confusion that it causes.